# react native render only part

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a feed and a bottom menu which can filter the feed.
When the filter is activated the feed reloads data from the API. 
However the root will always render causing the menu to collapse every time.
How can I make it so that the Feed only reloads?

```
var Main = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            reloadFeedData: false,
        };
    },
    reloadFeedData: function(){
        console.log('setting root state')
        this.setState({reloadFeedData:true});
    },
    renderScene: function(route, nav) {
        var reload = this.state.reloadFeedData
        switch (route.name) {
            case 'Feed':
                return (
                  <Feed navigator={nav} reloadFeedData={reload} />
                );
            default:
                return (
                    <Feed navigator={nav} reloadFeedData={reload} />
                );
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('root render');
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Navigator
                style={styles.navigator}
                renderScene={this.renderScene}
                initialRoute={{
          component: Feed,
        }}
                />
            <BottomMenu reloadFeedData={this.reloadFeedData} />
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question,
the issue was a bad componentWillReceiveProps which triggered on things it shouldnt.